# Show second element on checkbox checked action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've a code that show/hide (toggle) a div based on checkbox selection. The code is simple:

```
$(function () {
    $('#sucursal').on('click', function () {
        $("#rifEmpresa").toggle(!this.checked);
        $("#rifSucursal").toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

This works since `div#rifEmpresa` is hide and `div#rifSucursal` is show when checkbox is checked and viceversa. Now I have an additional condition and is when I check `checkbox#chkRif` is checked then I need to show `div#rifEmpresa` so I've done this code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#sucursal').on('click', function () {
        $("#rifEmpresa").toggle(!this.checked);
        $("#rifSucursal").toggle(this.checked);
    });

    $('#chkRif').on('click', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#rifEmpresa").removeAttr('style');
        } else {
            $("#rifEmpresa").attr('style', 'display:none');
        }
    });
});
```

But it's not working. I've tried several ways: using `$("#rifEmpresa").toggle(this.checked)`, using `$("#rifEmpresa").show() / $("#rifEmpresa").hide()` and none works. I setup a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0qgduuh/) for testing purposes, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezu76vv6/)**

```
$(function () {
    $('html').addClass('fuelux');

    //------ Toggle Sucursal Field
    $('#sucursal').on('click', function () {
        $("#rifEmpresa").toggle(!this.checked);
        $("#rifSucursal").toggle(this.checked);

        // ------ Turn rifSucursal search input in Select2 element
        $("#filtro").select2();
    });

    //------ Toggle Sucursal Field
    $('#chkRif').on('click', function () {
        if ($('input#chkRif').is(':checked')) {
            $("#rifEmpresa").removeAttr('style');
        } else {
            $("#rifEmpresa").attr('style', 'display:none');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need this

**Updated FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/h0qgduuh/3/

```
$(function () {
    $('html').addClass('fuelux');

    //------ Toggle Sucursal Field
    $('#sucursal').on('click', function () {
        $("#rifEmpresa").toggle(!this.checked);
        $("#rifSucursal").toggle(this.checked);

        // ------ Turn rifSucursal search input in Select2 element
        $("#filtro").select2();
    });

    //------ Toggle Sucursal Field
    $('#chkRif').on('click', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#rifEmpresa").removeAttr('style');
        } else {
            $("#rifEmpresa").attr('style', 'display:block');//changed display:none to display:block
        }
    });
});
```